# Drunk UNO Game: Who is "the player that gets reversed" in Uno?

Tags: uno

In the *Drunk UNO Game*, the rules say that when a Reverse is played,

> The person who gets reversed takes two shots

If A, B, and C are seated clockwise and play is still clockwise, then when B plays a reverse, it becomes A's turn.

Who is "the person who gets reversed" in this case?

The whole table is reversed.

Comment: Is it just a very poor wording to mean just player A?  It says 'the person' so we can assume it means a single player.   if it was a 'skip' card then there would be a player who 'gets skipped', maybe 'gets reversed' is just to refer to the first player affected by it?     I don't want to give this as an answer as no other evidence than gut feel.

Comment: @StartPlayer It's poor wording, for sure. My gut says the rules intend to refer to player C as the "victim" of the Reverse (but fail to do so unambiguously).

Answer (score 1):

When Player B plays a reverse it makes it Player A's turn which means that Player C would have gone next if the reverse hadn't been played. Following the same rules as the other action cards in UNO (skip, draw two etc.), the player who would play after Player B would be the player that would take the shots. in this circumstance it would be Player C.